# Why is my awk command not printing within the range I specified?

Tags: awk

I am trying to get awk to print the lines that have the values in column 2 between 71395943 - 72282539. Below is the command I ran.

gzip -cd ALL.wgs.integrated_phase1_v3.20101123.snps_indels_sv.sites.vcf.gz | awk {'if($2-1>="71395943" && $2-1<="72282539" && $2-2>="71395943" && $2-2<="72282539")print $1"\t"$2-1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$8"\t.\t+"'} > negr1_var.bed

and this is part of the output. All of the output starts with 7 but it is a lot smaller than the range I had specified. I am still new to using awk and would really appreciate any insight or an alternative method to accomplish the same thing. Thank you in advance!

```
1       72118   72119   rs199639004     AA=.;AC=8;AF=0.0037;AMR_AF=0.0028;AN=2184;ASN_AF=0.01;AVGPOST=0.9589;ERATE=0.0026;EUR_AF=0.0013;LDAF=0.0243;RSQ=0.2268;THETA=0.0016;VT=INDEL    .       +

1       72147   72148   rs182862337     AN=2184;RSQ=0.2794;THETA=0.0130;VT=SNP;AA=.;LDAF=0.0019;AVGPOST=0.9971;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AC=1;ERATE=0.0007;AF=0.0005;AMR_AF=0.0028
       .       +

1       713976  713977  rs74512038      ERATE=0.0004;AN=2184;VT=SNP;AA=.;AC=155;THETA=0.0019;AVGPOST=0.9916;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;LDAF=0.0723;RSQ=0.9544;AF=0.07;ASN_AF=0.22;AMR_AF=0.07;AFR_AF=0.01;EUR_AF=0.0040   .       +
```

Here is an example of the desired output

```
1       71396733  713957241  rs74512038      ERATE=0.0004;AN=2184;VT=SNP;AA=.;AC=155;THETA=0.0019;AVGPOST=0.9916;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;LDAF=0.0723;RSQ=0.9544;AF=0.07;ASN_AF=0.22;AMR_AF=0.07;AFR_AF=0.01;EUR_AF=0.0040   .       +
```

Example of input. The file is pretty large, 10582-10583 is where it starts and it ends at 249000000. I just want the lines between 71395943 - 72282539.

1       10582   10583   rs58108140      AVGPOST=0.7707;RSQ=0.4319;LDAF=0.2327;ERATE=0.0161;AN=2184;VT=SNP;AA=.;THETA=0.0046;AC=314;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AF=0.14;ASN_AF=0.13;AMR_AF=0.17;AFR_AF=0.04;EUR_AF=0.21     .       +

1       10610   10611   rs189107123     AN=2184;THETA=0.0077;VT=SNP;AA=.;AC=41;ERATE=0.0048;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AVGPOST=0.9330;LDAF=0.0479;RSQ=0.3475;AF=0.02;ASN_AF=0.01;AMR_AF=0.03;AFR_AF=0.01;EUR_AF=0.02      .       +

1       13301   13302   rs180734498     THETA=0.0048;AN=2184;AC=249;VT=SNP;AA=.;RSQ=0.6281;LDAF=0.1573;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;AVGPOST=0.8895;ERATE=0.0058;AF=0.11;ASN_AF=0.02;AMR_AF=0.08;AFR_AF=0.21;EUR_AF=0.14     .       +

1       13326   13327   rs144762171     AVGPOST=0.9698;AN=2184;VT=SNP;AA=.;RSQ=0.6482;AC=59;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;ERATE=0.0012;LDAF=0.0359;THETA=0.0204;AF=0.03;ASN_AF=0.02;AMR_AF=0.03;AFR_AF=0.02;EUR_AF=0.04      .       +

[example of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umPdV.png)

Comment: Could you please do update sample of input and expected output more clearly in your question in text format, that will make your question more clearly, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if($2-1>="71395943" && $2-1<="72282539" && $2-2>="71395943" &&
> $2-2<="72282539")

You should not use string literals when you desire numerical comparison as [Comparison Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html)

> When comparing operands of mixed types, numeric operands are converted
> to strings using the value of `CONVFMT`

and in effect you will get comparison using lexicographical order, consider that

```
awk 'END{print 20<=100;print 20<="100";print "20"<="100"}' emptyfile.txt
```

gives output

```
1
0
0
```

Explanation: when comparing *numbers* condtion does not hold, however when comparing number vs string is generally same as string vs string and does not hold as 1st character `2` has bigger ASCII code as `1` (0x32 vs 0x31).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: This really helped thank you! I was able to solve the issue by removing the quotations and running it as a numerical comparison instead